# How to configure internal middlewares for strapi v4?

Tags: middleware, strapi, koa

I was faced with this issue,

take for instance you want to configure `strapi::cors` middleware. according to the documentation we do

```
{
resolve: ‘strapi::cors’,
config: {
origin: [‘host1’, ‘host2’],
},
}
```

this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "name" property like this.

```
{
name: ‘strapi::cors’,
config: {
origin: [‘host1’, ‘host2’],
},
}
```

If it help you, vote up.